# karate: failed to use 'eval' in scenario step

Tags: karate

I need to call a .feature file in the scenario but don't care about the result. So I used eval like this:

```
eval if (gw == 'YES') karate.call('GatewayAuth.feature', authInfo)
```

But it shows that:

> "step 'eval if .....' doesn't have a glue code".

If I use:

```
def result = (gw == 'YES' ? karate.call('GatewayAuth.feature', authInfo) : null)
```

the step works fine.

What's wrong with the step use `eval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you are on an old version of Karate. `eval` was introduced in 0.7.0